# How to set up a multi-module project with equal hierarchy modules in IntelliJ?

Tags: module, intellij-idea, multi-module

I am wondering how to configure the following project layout in IntelliJ:

1. An Android application
2. A server back end feeding data to this application
3. Bean classes that are shared between back end and Android application

Initially, I wanted to create three modules on an equal hierarchy level. However, this does not seem to be possible with IntelliJ. I can only add new modules inside of the first module. I wonder if this is the way I am supposed to do it? Or is there a better way to do configure this project layout with IntelliJ? Do these hierarchies only represent folders?

I feel like I should make (3) a library module and add dependencies to (1) and (2). Since a module is defined as *a discrete unit of functionality which you can compile, run, test and debug independently* I feel like this is the right approach.

This is my first multi-module project in IntelliJ. Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: When creating a new project you can use the **Empty Project** option on the first wizard step. When the project is created, add 3 modules in different folders under the **Project Structure** settings.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I would +1 this if it was an answer and not a comment. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When creating a new project you can use the **Empty Project** option on the first wizard step. When the project is created, add 3 modules in different folders under the **Project Structure** settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add them on a *already initialized* project, the trick from @CrazyCoder works, but you must not choose Empty Project, but instead **Empty Module** (in the **Project Structure -> Modules** dialog).

Then, choose the existing project.

Lastly, on the right side, the content root might be wrong. Set it to the root of your module.

---

<sup>Make sure the submodules are not on root level on the Project Structure -> Modules page. If they are, remove all expect the root module, delete the content root on the right, and add it again.</sup>